# $scope function and ng-disable not functioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angularjs-scope

Below is the JS of my angular JS Web App:

```
$scope.total = 50000000;

var ref = databaseService.players;


$scope.players = $firebaseArray(ref);


$scope.picked = [];
$scope.history = [];

 $scope.buy = function(player) {
        //remove if already added locally
        var index = $scope.history.indexOf(player);
        var index2 = $scope.picked.indexOf(player.id);
        if(index>=0 || index2>=0 ){
            $scope.history.splice(index,1);
            $scope.picked.splice(index2,1);
            PlayerService.removePlayerFromSelection(player);
            return;
        }

        //max 6 allowed
        if($scope.history.length>=6 || $scope.picked.length>=6){
            alert('max 6 allowed');
            return;
        }
        //to make sure moeny doesn't go below $50,000,000
        if($scope.total<0){
            alert('Oops! You have run out of cash');
            return;
        }

        var selected = $scope.history.reduce(function(a,b){
            a[b.position] = (a[b.position] || 0) + 1;
            return a;
        }, {}) || {};

        if(!selected[player.position] || selected[player.position]<2 && $scope.total>0){
            $scope.history.push(player);
            $scope.picked.push(player.id);
            PlayerService.addPlayerToSelection(player);       
        }else{
            alert('You can add only two players per position');

        }
      };

      $scope.getTotal = function(){
        return $scope.history.reduce(function(tot, p){
            tot = tot - p.price;
            return tot;
            if (tot <0){
                alert('Oops! You have run out of money')
            }
        }, $scope.total);
      }; 
  $scope.saveTeam = function(){
   userRef.set( $scope.picked);       
   $location.path('/mySquad');
   };
```

MY issue

Is there a way to alert the user when the total goes lower than 0? I tried adding an if statement into the buy() function but it did not work. I aim to have the user alerted when the total budget goes below 0.

Alternative

Another option i tired is to have the "save team" button disabled if the result of the function `getTotal` results in a value less than 0. Below is the HTML code i tried but was unsuccessful with:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-md " ng-disabled="history.length<6" ng-disabled="getTotal<0" ng-click="saveTeam()" > Save Team </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to rewrite the function as below. You need to change the place for return statement

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
        return $scope.history.reduce(function(tot, p){
            tot = tot - p.price;

            if (tot <0){
                alert('Oops! You have run out of money')
            }
           return tot; //changed location of this line
        }, $scope.total);
      };
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem now is that once the user goes below 0, the page continuously alerts the users with the message 'Oops! You have run out of money' without giving the user the opportunity to deselect the selected player. Could it be something that has to do with the position of the return?

Answer (score 0):

Here,your code after return statement wont' execute. remove `return tot` or move it to below if condition.

```
 $scope.getTotal = function(){
    return $scope.history.reduce(function(tot, p){
        tot = tot - p.price;
        return tot; // wrong place of return statement
        if (tot <0){ // it won't execute, coz, it was returned before line itself
            alert('Oops! You have run out of money')
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem now is that once the user goes below 0, the page continuously alerts the users with the message 'Oops! You have run out of money' without giving the user the opportunity to deselect the selected player. Could it be something that has to do with the position of the return?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
 return $scope.history.reduce(function(tot, p){
    tot = tot - p.price;

    if (tot <0){ 
        alert('Oops! You have run out of money')
        return tot; // If you place here once you come here it will return
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that once a player is selected, the budget value (50000000 - the player price) disappears